# Live activity request fails silently on UIKit while it works on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, dynamic-island, widgetliveactivity

I have an issue with Live Activities. While i can start it with SwiftUI project and same configuration starts displays and updates Live Activity lock screen widget and Dynamic island, on UIKit it fails silently god knows why.

Particular `Activity<UploadingAttributes.self>.request()`fails silently no error or such.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

My attribute class

```swift
struct UploadingAttributes : ActivityAttributes {

    struct ContentState : Codable, Hashable {
        var progressValue : CGFloat = 0
    }
}
```

My live activity widget

```swift
struct UploadingActivityLiveActivity: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: UploadingAttributes.self) { context in
           
           Rectangle()
                .fill(.mint)

        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
                    Text("Uploading")
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
                   Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill")
                }
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
                    ProgressView(value: context.state.progressValue)
                        .progressViewStyle(.linear)
                }
           
            } compactLeading: {
                Text("L")
            } compactTrailing: {
                Text("T")
            } minimal: {
                Text("Min")
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

My view controller

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var button : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Activate Activity", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .systemMint
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startActivities), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func startActivities(_ sender: Any?) {
        let attributes = UploadingAttributes()
        let state = UploadingAttributes.ContentState()
     
        do  {
            try Activity<UploadingAttributes>.request(
                attributes: attributes,
                content: .init(state: state, staleDate: .now) )
        } catch(let e) {
            print(e)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a delay between UIKit and SwiftUI transactions. So when you invoke request immediately its not working, 1 sec delay worked.

```swift
  do  {
            try Activity<UploadingAttributes>.request(
                attributes: attributes,
                content: .init(state: state, staleDate: .now + 1)) 
                                         // use .now + 1 instead of .now
        } catch(let e) {
            print(e)
        }
```